# problems with backup and tar in command line

Tags: command-line, backup, tar, mkdir

I am studying for a Linux certification from the Linux foundation but I have some questions about one lab. Here is the lab:

> Create a directory called backup and in it place a compressed tar archive of all the files under /usr/include, with
>   the highest level directory being include. You can use any compression method (gzip, bzip2 or xzip).

I started with `mkdir backup` and then `tar -C /usr -zcf include.tar.gz include`:

```
harrydevries@harrydevries-410-100nd:/usr$ tar -C /usr -zcf include.tar.gz include
tar (child): include.tar.gz: Functie open() is mislukt: Toegang geweigerd
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Can anyone help? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04
Harry de Vries

Comment: My dutch is not very good but I think `tar` tells you that it was denied permission to the `/usr` folder. Try `sudo tar zcvf include.tar.gz include .`

Comment: **_I actually wanted to comment since I can't I've to do this way_**.What you're doing is compressing the actual `/use/include` folder which is wrong I guess because of dependencies issues.
Instead what you have to do is make a copy of all the files and folders to your `backup` folder and compress it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output of the same command with `LC-ALL=C` before it: `LC_ALL=C tar -C ...`.

Comment: seems reasonable i will try , copy and than tar everyting

Comment: What dependency issues? The `tar` command won't replace any of the existing files, it will make a copy.

Comment: Thats what i'm talking about Mr. Terdon you can't tar in the same directory which the system uses.

Comment: Of course you can, you just need to have permission to write to it. Unlike say `gzip`, `tar` will not replace the existing files. It just creates an archive with a copy of each of them. It doesn't affect the existing files in any way whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having put your error through Google translate, the problem is (obviously enough) a question of permissions. Next time, please either translate the error messages or —even better—prepend `LC_ALL=C` to any command you run so the errors can be in English.

Anyway, the error is:

```
$ cd /usr ; tar zcvf include.tar.gz include
tar (child): include.tar.gz: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
include/
include/cairomm-1.0/
include/cairomm-1.0/cairomm/
include/cairomm-1.0/cairomm/win32_surface.h
include/cairomm-1.0/cairomm/surface.h
```

This is because you are trying to run this from the `/usr` directory and are specifying that the archive should be created in `/usr` as well. To avoid this, either give a path for the tar ball:

```
mkdir ~/backup; cd /usr ; tar zcvf ~/backup/include.tar.gz include
```

Or, even better, don't `cd` to `/usr` at all:

```
mkdir ~/backup; tar zcvf ~/backup/include.tar.gz /usr/include
```

Comment: Thanx terdon this worked out fine, i understand now .